# determine column having numeric or string in oracle

Tags: string, oracle, date, case

I need to find whether the value is numeric or not. For example i had a date value with data type as varchar2. I need to find the column returns only numeric or not. Need to handle this with case in oracle.

```
select case when d.data_type ='DATE' then to_char(to_date(v.value,'YYYYMMDD'),'DD-MM-YY') else v.value end as "Value" from data_type d , value v ;
```

In this example the v.value can contain string values. But i need to check whether the column having value as number in Case statement. Please help me on this. Expected query is

```
select case when d.data_type ='DATE' and 'd.value haing number only' then to_char(to_date(v.value,'YYYYMMDD'),'DD-MM-YY') else v.value end as "Value" from data_type d , value v ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_like` to see if the value has only numbers:

```
select (case when regexp_like(date, '[^0-9]') then 'NonNumeric'
             else 'Numeric'
        end)
```

Note:  this checks only for digits.  If you allow other characters(such as '-', '.', '+', ','), then the regular expression can be easily modified for that purpose.